# FFMpeg - PhantomJS to Youtube Live

Tags: youtube, ffmpeg, phantomjs, live, image2pipe

I'm trying to stream a webpage captured with PhantomJS to Youtube using FMMpeg.
This is the command I use:

```
xvfb-run phantomjs --web-security=no render.js | ffmpeg -threads 0 -y -v verbose -c:v png -r 30 -f image2pipe -i - -f lavfi -i anullsrc -strict -2 -acodec aac -ac 1 -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -s 1280x720 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/key";
```

And the render.js code:
http://pastebin.com/raw/X9gv8iGH

It looks like it's streaming, but no feed is received by YouTube, and I can't see where the problem is.
[Outpout from my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvYoW.png)

Comment: Why `xvfb-run`? (PhantomJS is headless) Have you tried watching the stream with a player?

Comment: PhantomJS won't start without xvfb-run.
I tried exporting it into an flv video but it plays just a black screen.

Comment: I ran the script for 5 seconds and it made a 48 minutes long video...

Comment: `won't start without xvfb-run` What version of PhantomJS do you run and in what environment?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
phantomjs --web-security=no render.js | ffmpeg -threads 0 -y -v verbose -c:v png -framerate 33 -f image2pipe -i - -f lavfi -i anullsrc -strict -2 -acodec aac -ac 1 -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -s 1280x720 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 60 -r 30 -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/key";
```

Parameter -framerate:

> You can specify two frame rates: input and output.
>      Set input frame rate with the -framerate input option (before -i). The default for reading inputs is -framerate 25 which will be set if
>   no -framerate is specified.
>       The output frame rate for the video stream by setting -r after -i or by using the fps filter.

So in your case framerate should be 1/period_from_phantomjs which is 1000/30 = 33.33

As for the -g 60, that will add a key frame every 2 seconds, which is probably a requirement for the youtube streaming api (I know that for facebook it is).

Comment: This works but outputs a very low FPS (about 2.5). Apart from that it streams. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: thats maybe because phantomjs rendering is choking the cpu, and there is not enough input going into ffmpeg.

Comment: Yeap, very slow.